# Python WebSocket Decoding Message

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

So Im making a WebSocket Server in Python for my own purposes and I need to decypher the data recieved from the network. it's all in some jibberjabbish, can anyone help me figure out what it means?

```
while True:
    data = self.socket.recv(1024)
    print bytes(data)
```

that's my current code, though it just returns some weird characters. How do you make this into normal text? I have read the other topic on it, but the answers didn't help (were specific to his weird PHP stuff) and the links were dead.

Comment: Who is sending the data? Is the client written by you?

Comment: The client is an HTML page that use Google Chrome to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a WebSocket server, you should be studying the [WebSocket RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) in great detail. In particular, you want to be looking at [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4) which describes the initial request from the client to the server and the response the server must send, and [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) that describes the way individual packets of data to or from the client are encoded.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me create a function that gets part by part and decodes to usable information

Answer (score 0):

At default websockets using base64 encodings, so:

```
import base64
print base64.decodestring(message_from_socket)
```

Comment: and what client lib you use? SocketIO ?

Comment: i am using google chrome, but I have made a function using Screwtape's answer.

Answer (score 0):

print bytes(data.decode())

Perhaps this might work? Sorry, its my first time answering here. And I know that I personally had to encode data before sending it, and then decode it when it arrives.